# Updating a table using entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to update a field in a table using the following Entity Framework code but it just will not seem to modify the field. This is really frustrating so I wondered if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

default.aspx.vb:

```
    Protected Sub btn_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
        SaveNewsBox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetNewsBox()
        Dim newsBox As GLC.Home = BLL.Homes.Homes.GetNewsBox()
        If newsBox IsNot Nothing Then
            txt_NewsBox.Text = newsBox.NewsBox
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveNewsBox()

        Dim newsBox As New GLC.Home

        newsBox.NewsBox = txt_NewsBox.Text

        If BLL.Homes.Homes.Update(newsBox) Then
            Master.AlertStyle = "alert-success"
            Master.AlertMessage = "<i class=""fa fa-thumbs-o-up""></i> Meal details saved, <a href=""/secure/"">return to main menu.</a>"
            Master.AlertVisible = True
        Else
            Master.AlertStyle = "alert-danger"
            Master.AlertMessage = "<i class=""fa fa-thumbs-o-down""></i> Warning news box details could not be saved.</a>"
            Master.AlertVisible = True
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Homes.vb:

```
Imports DAL
Imports GLC

Namespace Homes
    Public Class Homes
        Public Shared Function GetNewsBox() As Home
            Return MethodClasses.HomesHandler.GetNewsBox()
        End Function

        Public Shared Function Update(newsBox As Home) As Boolean
            Return MethodClasses.HomesHandler.Update(newsBox)
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

HomesHandler.vb:

```
Imports GLC
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic

Namespace MethodClasses
    Public Class HomesHandler

        Public Shared Function GetNewsBox() As Home
            Using context As New GLCContext
                Try
                    Return context.Homes.Single()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return Nothing
                End Try
            End Using
        End Function

        Public Shared Function Update(newsBox As Home) As Boolean
            Dim newsBoxUpdated As Boolean = False
            Using context As New GLCContext
                Try
                    context.Homes.Attach(newsBox)
                    Dim entry = context.Entry(newsBox)
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified

                    context.SaveChanges()
                    newsBoxUpdated = True

                Catch ex As Exception
                    newsBoxUpdated = False
                End Try
            End Using

            Return newsBoxUpdated

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: No error ? At least you do not seems to provide a PK value for newsBox, or a value always equal to 0.

Comment: If you remove you try/catch from your Update() function do you get an error? Also, are you able to share your schema?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm guessing happens is, when you call `Dim entry = context.Entry(newsBox)` it throws an exception and returns false, since this object is the new one you created in the aspx and it can't find it.

It appears that there is only ever a single entry in your table (or you only provide a way to get the first row). If that's the case, I would just do this:

```
Public Shared Function Update(newsBox As Home) As Boolean
            Dim newsBoxUpdated As Boolean = False
            Using context As New GLCContext
                Try
                    Dim entry = GetNewsBox()
                    entry.NewsBox = newsBox.NewsBox

                    context.SaveChanges()
                    newsBoxUpdated = True

                Catch ex As Exception
                    newsBoxUpdated = False
                End Try
            End Using

            Return newsBoxUpdated

        End Function
```

The context will know that the entity is modified (since you changed it while it was attached). If you call Attach() without a key (or some way for EF to identify the given object with a specific row) then it will end up inserting a new row, but you'll probably never see it because you only ever get Single().

You could save some overhead and make it simpler, if this really is the only property you modify, by simply passing the textbox's value as a string into the Update function instead of passing a new, empty (except a single field) object.